# Want to display an image from SD card to ILI9486 LCD display

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, spi, sd-card

I am completely new to Arduino. I have been given a side project to display a image from SD card to display. LCD used is ILI9486 which has a SD card slot at the back of the display module. I have inserted an 1 GB micro SD card. I am using below example code to try to open the SD card and display the image on display module. I am getting error on serial monitor "Initializing sd card - failed". Can anyone let me know how to display image from SD card to screen.

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TFT.h>  // Arduino LCD library

// pin definition for the Uno
#define sd_cs  4
#define lcd_cs 10
#define dc     9
#define rst    8

TFT TFTscreen = TFT(lcd_cs, dc, rst);

// this variable represents the image to be drawn on screen
PImage logo;

void setup() {
    // initialize the GLCD and show a message
    // asking the user to open the serial line
    TFTscreen.begin();
    TFTscreen.background(255, 255, 255);

    TFTscreen.stroke(0, 0, 255);
    TFTscreen.println();
    TFTscreen.println(F("Arduino TFT Bitmap Example"));
    TFTscreen.stroke(0, 0, 0);
    TFTscreen.println(F("Open serial monitor"));
    TFTscreen.println(F("to run the sketch"));

    // initialize the serial port: it will be used to
    // print some diagnostic info
    Serial.begin(9600);

    while (!Serial) {
        // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
    }

    // clear the GLCD screen before starting
    TFTscreen.background(255, 255, 255);

    // try to access the SD card. If that fails (e.g.
    // no card present), the setup process will stop.
    Serial.print(F("Initializing SD card..."));
    if (!SD.begin(sd_cs)) {
        Serial.println(F("failed!"));
        return;
    }
    Serial.println(F("OK!"));

    // initialize and clear the GLCD screen
    TFTscreen.begin();
    TFTscreen.background(255, 255, 255);

    // now that the SD card can be access, try to load the
    // image file.
    logo = TFTscreen.loadImage("arduino.bmp");
    if (!logo.isValid()) {
        Serial.println(F("error while loading arduino.bmp"));
    }
}

void loop() {
    // don't do anything if the image wasn't loaded correctly.
    if (logo.isValid() == false) {
        return;
    }

    Serial.println(F("drawing image"));

    // get a random location where to draw the image.
    // To avoid the image to be draw outside the screen,
    // take into account the image size.
    int x = random(TFTscreen.width() - logo.width());
    int y = random(TFTscreen.height() - logo.height());

    // draw the image to the screen
    TFTscreen.image(logo, x, y);

    // wait a little bit before drawing again
    delay(1500);
}
```

Comment: Most SD card modules don't allow other chips on the same SPI bus

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. I was able to resolve the issue of initializing sd card failing. i made the sd_cs value as 10 and it worked. But now I am running into another problem. 
I am facing issue during loading of image from sd card. Getting error: "loadImage: file not found: arduino.bmp
error while loading arduino.bmp"

I am using 1 gb sd card and the size of bmp image is 7.5kb. its a 50x50 pixel 24 bit bmp image. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your SD card is Fat16 format.  At least that was a requirement of the test code I had on the same sort of display.